# CSV Leading Zeros

Tags: excel, csv, leading-zero

I got the CSV file which may have some columns with leading Zeros .
If viewed in Excel leading zeros are not shown as they are treated as number .
Later this CSV has to be send to Sage 50 as import record.

My issue is that I want to see the **leading zeros when file is opened in excel** . However I don't want to do add anything in file itself as it has to be added in Sage records. It might not be possible .But still any work around.

Comment: I had check the link earlier . Changing the CSV file extension or using VBA code was not possible for me. that's why I asked

Answer (score 2):

Do you open the .csv with Excel directly?

If so, try importing the .csv file into Excel instead:

1. Save the .csv
2. Start a new instance of Excel
3. Under the Data tab, Get External Data group, select From Text
4. Select your .csv file
5. Select 'Delimited' then 'Next'
6. Select the Comma as the delimiter then Next
7. Click on the column(s) that you would like to retain the leading zeroes, and under 'Column data format' choose text
8. Repeat for any column that you need to retain leading zeroes
9. Click Finish

There is an illustrated example of this method [here](http://www.upenn.edu/computing/da/bo/webi/qna/iv_csvLeadingZeros.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use Data \ From Text to import the csv file in excel rather than opening it. When you do the import, specify the formats of the columns as text to avoid having them reformatted.